# Applying ICC profile to a color

Tags: colors, color-space

I have [this ICC file](https://www.photopea.com/HDTV.icc), which converts colors from RGB to XYZ. I am making my own ICC processor.

I want to convert a value [0.5, 0.5, 0.5] to XYZ and then, to sRGB. Here is what I get:

```
RGB = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
apply "A2B0": 
XYZ = [0.1263921901414079, 0.13108369512741044, 0.1081292238059337]
to sRGB using "wtpt":
RGB = [0.39734262390746755, 0.39732431073870283, 0.3972382158377442]
```

However, the resulting sRGB should be different (brighter). There is also a "chad" tag (3x3 matrix), but I don't know when to apply it. How should the color [0.5, 0.5, 0.5] be handled by this ICC profile?

Answer (score 1):

The link to your ICC profile is dead (says file is deleted).

But also: you need to linearize any gamma or TRC on the RGB before matrixing to XYZ, and must re-apply the TRC when going to sRGB.

And you must use the 3x3 matrix in and the reverse 3x3 matrix out.

AND: if you are using v2 or v4 ICC profiles, you also must do a chromatic adaptation to (and from) D50 as that is specified as the adapted WP of the ICC XYZ PCS. sRGB is D65, but the primaries in an ICC profile would be the D50 *adapted* primaries.

If you are starting with **sRGB** `#808080`, the D50 XYZ values should be something like:

```
      0.20815334    0.21586051    0.17810748
```

Though since I can't see the ICC profile I don't know exactly what space you are coming from.

#### Matrix Math

The short explanation is each output channel is the sum of the products of the associated matrix line.

Here's the example, also this is the D65 matrix not the D50 adapted matrix:

```
|R|0.4123907993  0.3575843394  0.1804807884|   |X|
|G|0.2126390059  0.7151686788  0.0721923154| = |Y|
|B|0.0193308187  0.1191947798  0.9505321522|   |Z|
```

Here we are going from linear sRGB to XYZ. The sRGB TRC (gamma) must be removed before applying this matrix (not shown). The first column of the matrix is R, second column G, third B. The top ROW is X, middle Y, then Z.

So multiply each column row by it's input channel, then sum each row to the output channel.

```
R * 0.4123907993 + G * 0.3575843394 + B * 0.1804807884 = X
R * 0.2126390059 + G * 0.7151686788 + B * 0.0721923154 = Y
R * 0.0193308187 + G * 0.1191947798 + B * 0.9505321522 = Z
```

XYZ space is linear (no gamma) so you need to put the TRC back onto sRGB after coming out of XYZ.

Comment: Hi have fixed the link, could you do computations according to that ICC?

Comment: hi @IvanKuckir That ICC file is for Rec709, which is virtually the same as sRGB except for the TRC. So as I understand you, you want the RGB = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5] to be interpreted via this HDTV profile, and come out as sRGB?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5] is in HDTV space and I want to get the sRGB.

Comment: Because Rec709 and sRGB use the same primaries and whitepoint, you don't need an ICC profile (unless you want to do lots of other spaces). For your use case, all you need to do is convert the transfer function. First linearize the RGB channels of the source, then apply the gamma of the destination. You need to convert 0-255 to 0.0-1.0 to do this. Where V is one of the RGB channels, the sloppy way is: ` Vsrgb = min(((Vhd/255.0)^1.9)^0.45)*255 , 255); ` for the first exponent, instead of 1.9, you might want 2.4, and yes I know I am skipping the piecewise TRC for sRGB.

Comment: I am making a program, which receives an ICC profile as the input. There can be millions of ICC profiles, so I need to do the conversion using the ICC, not by detecting four or five specific cases. Could you describe the conversion using that specific ICC?

Comment: Hi @IvanKuckir okay, I will this week, a little over worked at the moment but mid week... in the meantime, the ful specifications are available at color.org

Comment: is it possible to get in touch with you? I could even pay you for your help. I don't know anyone else in the world with such knowledge :( could you write me to support@photopea.com ?

Comment: Hi @IvanKuckir sorry I have been so busy — and yea, this is a narrow field to be sure. Sending you an email shortly.

Comment: hey, could you send me an email? I need some help with handling the ICC profiles and I don't know anyone in the world who could help me :/ I feel I am doing everything according to the latest ICC specification, but it still does not work :(